# Mongoose: Chaining distinct() with find()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to find some distinct values after querying the collection for certain values.

Eg : 
My model is that of students. Fields in each document are name, subject, marks.

Now i want to get the distinct subjects for a student named 'Mark'. I was trying:
`students.find({"name":"Mark"}).distinct("subject")`
This gives me an error that `db.getCollection(...).find(...).distinct is not a function`

I understand that the same can be achieved by using aggregrate pipeline but the question is why cant these two be chained?

Comment: If the below answer worked for you. Please care to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the Mongoose API [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct), you can use something like this:

```
distinct(field, conditions)
```

so in your case it would be something like this:

```
students.distinct("subject", { "name": "Mark" })
```

If you are trying to do the same in `mongo-shell`. You can try this:

```
db.runCommand({
          distinct : "students",
          key : "subject",
          query : {"name":"Mark"}
})
```

For `distinct` command you can refer the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/).